# Error in Reading Bean

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-search

I have prepared an application from start.spring.io

The name is SpringBootWebManyToManyApplication(Artifact Id)

Group id is com,com.controller,repository,model,service

I get the following error :

```
Invalid property 'persons' of bean class [com.model.Person]: Bean property 'persons' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
```

//////////////////////////////Main App////////////////////////////////

```
package com;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootWebManyToManyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootWebManyToManyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

////////////////////////////////IndexController///////////////////////

```
package com.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class IndexController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/")
    String index(){
        return "index";
    }
}
```

///////////////////////////////PersonController////////////////////////

```
package com.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;


import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.model.Person;
//import com.model.PersonDetail;
import com.service.PersonService;

@Controller
public class PersonController {

    Person person = new Person();

    private PersonService personService;


     @Autowired
        public void setPersonService(PersonService personService) {
            this.personService = personService;
        }

     @RequestMapping(value = "/persons", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String list(Model model){
            model.addAttribute("persons", personService.listAllPersons());
            System.out.println("Returning Persons");
            return "persons";
        }




        @RequestMapping("person/{id}")
        public String showPerson(@PathVariable Integer id, Model model){
            model.addAttribute("person", personService.getPersonById(id));          
            return "personshow";
        }



        @RequestMapping("person/edit/{id}")
        public String edit(@PathVariable Integer id, Model model){
            model.addAttribute("person", personService.getPersonById(id));
            return "personform";
        }


        @RequestMapping("person/new")
        public String newPerson(Model model){
            model.addAttribute("person", new Person());
            return "personform";
        }


        @RequestMapping("person")
        public String savePerson(Person person){
            personService.savePerson(person);
           //return "personform";
           return "redirect:/person/" + person.getId();
        }


        @RequestMapping("person/delete/{id}")
        public String delete(@PathVariable Integer id){
            personService.deletePerson(id);
            return "redirect:/persons/";
            //return "persons";
            /*return "persons";*/

        }


}
```

///////////////////////////////Person.java////////////////////////////

```
package com.model;





import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Access;
import javax.persistence.AccessType;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;





@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class Person implements Serializable{


    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name = "id",unique=true,nullable=false)
        private Integer id; 
        @Column(name = "name", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 10)
        private String name;            
        @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinTable(name = "person_person_Detail", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "person_id", 
        referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "personDetails_id",
        referencedColumnName = "id"))
        private Set<PersonDetail> personDetails;



        public Integer getId() {
            return this.id;
        }
        public void setId(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        /**
         * @return the personDetails
         */
        /**
         * @return the personDetails
         */
        public Set<PersonDetail> getPersonDetails() {
            return personDetails;
        }
        /**
         * @param personDetails the personDetails to set
         */
        public void setPersonDetails(Set<PersonDetail> personDetails) {
            this.personDetails = personDetails;
        }



        }
```

///////////////////////////PersonDetail//////////////////////

```
package com.model;


import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;





@Entity
@Table(name="personDetails")
public class PersonDetail implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Integer id;     
    @Column(name = "address", nullable = false, length = 20)
    private String address; 
    @Column(name = "age", nullable = false,length=10)
    private Integer age;    
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "personDetails")
    private Set<Person> persons;


    /**
     * @return the persons
     */
    public Set<Person> getPersons() {
        return persons;
    }


    /**
     * @param persons the persons to set
     */
    public void setPersons(Set<Person> persons) {
        this.persons = persons;
    }


    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }


    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public String getAddress() {
        return this.address;
    }


    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }


    public Integer getAge() {
        return this.age;

    }


    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Set<Person> getPerson() {
        return persons;
    }

    public void setPerson(Set<Person> persons) {
        this.persons = persons;

    }


}
```

////////////////////////////PersonRepository/////////////////////////

```
package com.repository;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.model.PersonDetail;
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface PersonDetailRepository extends CrudRepository<PersonDetail, Integer>{

}
```

/////////////////////////////////PersonRepository//////////////////////

```
package com.repository;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.model.Person;
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Integer>{
}
```

/////////////////////////PersonService/////////////////////////////////

```
package com.service;

import com.model.Person;




public interface PersonService {
     Iterable<Person> listAllPersons();

        Person getPersonById(Integer id);

        Person savePerson(Person person);

        void deletePerson(Integer id);

}
```

///////////////////////////////PersonServiceImpl///////////////

```
package com.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.model.Person;
//import com.model.PersonDetail;
import com.repository.PersonRepository;
@Service
public class PersonServiceImpl implements PersonService{
    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository personRepository;

        public void setPersonRepository(PersonRepository personRepository) {
            this.personRepository = personRepository;

        }   


    @Override
    public Iterable<Person> listAllPersons() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         return personRepository.findAll();

        }

    @Override
    public Person getPersonById(Integer id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return personRepository.findOne(id);
    }

    @Override
    public Person savePerson(Person person) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        return personRepository.save(person);
    }
     @Override
        public void deletePerson(Integer id) {
            personRepository.delete(id);

        }

}
```

/////////////////////////////templates-header/////////////////////////

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head lang="en">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
  <!--   <link href="../static/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          th:href="@{/css/bootstrap.min.css}"
          rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>


    <link href="../../static/css/style.css"
          th:href="@{css/style.css}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/> -->
</head>
<body>

<!-- <div class="container">
    <div th:fragment="header">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" th:href="@{/}">Home</a>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="#" th:href="@{/products}">Products</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" th:href="@{/product/new}">Create Product</a></li>
                    </ul>

                </div>
            </div> -->
       <!--  </nav> -->

     <!--    <div class="jumbotron">
            <div class="row text-center">
                <div class="">
                    <h2>Spring Boot Exemple</h2>

                    <h3>Bienvenue</h3>
                </div>
            </div> -->
           <!--  <div class="row text-center">
                <img src="../../static/images/boot.png" width="200"
                     th:src="@{/images/boot.png}"/>
            </div> -->
      <!--   </div>
    </div>
</div> -->
</body>
</html>
```

/////////////////////////////headerinc.html/////////////////////////

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head lang="en" th:fragment="head">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
   <!--  <link href="../static/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          th:href="@{/css/bootstrap.min.css}"
          rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />

    <link href="../static/css/style.css"
          th:href="@{/css/style.css}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>
 --></head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

///////////////////////////////index.html/////////////////////////

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head lang="en">

    <title>Spring Boot Example</title>
    <!-- <th:block th:include="fragments/headerinc :: head"></th:block> -->
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div th:fragment="header">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <!-- <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" th:href="@{/}">Home</a> -->
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="#" th:href="@{/persons}">Persons</a></li>
                        <li><a th:href="@{/person/new}">Add Person</a>  </li>
                      </ul>

                </div>
            </div></nav></div>
<!-- <div class="container"> -->
   <!--  <th:block th:include="fragments/header :: header"></th:block> -->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

/////////////////////////////personform.html/////////////////////

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head lang="en">

    <title>Spring Boot Example</title>

     <th:block th:include="fragments/headerinc :: head"></th:block> 
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <th:block th:include="fragments/header :: header"></th:block> 

    <h2>Person Details</h2>
    <div>

    <!-- th:object="${person}" --> 

        <form class="form-horizontal" th:object="${person}" th:action="@{/person}"  method="post">
             <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}"/> 

            <!-- <div class="form-group">
                 <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Person Id:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{id}"/> 
                </div> 
            </div> -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{name}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
             <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Address:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{persons.personDetails.address}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
             <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Age:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{persons.personDetail.age}"/>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>

          <a href="#" th:href="@{/}">Back</a>

    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

////////////////////////////////persons.html/////////////////////////

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head lang="en">

    <title>Persons</title>

   <th:block th:include="fragments/headerinc :: head"></th:block> 
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">

  <!--   <th:block th:include="fragments/header :: header"></th:block> /*/ -->
    <div th:if="${not #lists.isEmpty(persons)}">
     <b><font size="4">Person List</font></b>          

                <table class="table table-striped" border="1">

            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Person Id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                 <th>Operations</th>              
            </tr>

            <tr th:each="person : ${persons}">
                <td th:text="${person.id}"><a href="/person/${person.id}">Id</a></td>
                <td th:text="${person.id}">Person Id</td>
                <td th:text="${person.name}">Name</td>
                <td th:text="${person.personDetails.address}">Address</td>
                <td th:text="${person.personDetails.age}">Age</td>

                <td><a th:href="${ '/person/' + person.id}">View</a> <a th:href="${'/person/edit/' + person.id}">Update</a>  <a th:href="${'/person/delete/' + person.id}">Delete</a></td>

   </tr>

        </table>
         <a href="#" th:href="@{/}">Back</a>   <br/>                                                                       
         <a th:href="@{/person/new}">Add Person</a>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

//////////////////////////////personshow.html//////////////////////

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head lang="en">

    <title>Person Details</title>

    <th:block th:include="fragments/headerinc :: head"></th:block> 
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <!--/*/ <th:block th:include="fragments/header :: header"></th:block> /*/-->

    <h2>Person Details</h2>
        <div>
            <form class="form-horizontal" th:action="@{/person}" th:object="${person}" method="get">

                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label"><b>Person Id:</b></label>

                        <p class="form-control-static" th:text="${id}">Person Id</p>


                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label"><b>Name:</b></label>

                        <p class="form-control-static" th:text="${person.name}">name</p>



                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label"><b>Address:</b></label>

                        <p class="form-control-static" th:text="${person.personDetails.address}">address</p>



                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label"><b>Age</b></label>

                        <p class="form-control-static" th:text="${person.personDetails.age}">age</p>



       <a href="#" th:href="@{/persons}">Person List</a>

            </form>

    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

/////////////////////////////application.properties////////////////////

```
#logging.level.org.h2.server: DEBUG
# Database
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myschema
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=admin123

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Comment: any clues about this??

Comment: Please tell me if any more files are needed\

Comment: my src/main/resources contains the following